# Drop down operations using jQuery

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down list as below.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Drop down trial
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#country").change(function(){
                        alert($(this).attr('id'));
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
            <select name="country" id="country">
                <option id="0">Country</option>
                <option id="1">India</option>
                <option id="2">China</option>
                <option id="3">Japan</option>
                <option id="4">US</option>
                <option id="5">UK</option>
            </select>

    </body>
</html>
```

Below are my queries:
1) Above code is not working however same code works when I use the script tags in body after select element. I have used document.ready also however it still does not work as mentioned above. What could be possible reason for this.
2) I want to get the id of the option selected however everytime it returns the id of drop down i.e. country. Please suggest on this as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Amit Joki said, reposition your script. Currently it will select the id of the select element. If you want to get the options id, use like this.

```
$("#country").change(function(){
    alert($(this).find("option:selected").attr('id'));
  });
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/458/)

Answer (score 1):

`<script>` should not be present in `<title>`. It should either be in the `<body>` or in the `<head>`
Therefore your html is invalid and won't work and you should use

`$(this).children(":selected")[0].id` to find the id of the selected option:

```
$("#country").change(function(){
   alert($(this).children(":selected")[0].id);
});
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/title) says:

> The HTML  element (HTML Title Element) defines the title of the
>   document, shown in a browser's title bar or on the page's tab. It can
>   only contain text and any contained tags are not interpreted.

Comment: Thanks..that was a silly mistake from my end, also how can I get the ID of option selected from drop down.

Answer (score 0):

You should put `<script>` inside `<head>` or `<body>` tag and not `<title>` tag.

And use below script to get `id` of selected option where find option with value equal to dropdown value and get it's `id`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Drop down trial
        </title>
           <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#country").change(function(){
                        var optionId = $(this).find('option[value="'+$(this).val()+'"]:first').attr('id');
                        // Or you can find selected option
                       // var optionId = $(this).find('option:selected:first').attr('id');
                        alert(optionId);
                    });
                });
            </script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <select name="country" id="country">
                <option id="0">Country</option>
                <option id="1">India</option>
                <option id="2">China</option>
                <option id="3">Japan</option>
                <option id="4">US</option>
                <option id="5">UK</option>
            </select>

    </body>
</html>
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/w0nnxw75/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

Script tags inside the title tag is bad idea :)

You should move all your javascript codes to the end of the document so that the page will not wait for javascripts to run before rendering.

```
<html>
....
    <body>
....
...
...
    </body>
            <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script>
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#country").change(function(){
                        alert($(this).attr('id'));
                    });
                });
            </script>
</html>
```